# Model is always NULL on form post to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I submit the form the model passed into the controller is NULL. I've spent ages looking at this. I think I am missing something fundamental here.

```
@model VisitorPortal.Models.ReinviteVisitorModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateMeeting", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3>Reinvitation Details</h3>
    <div>The information entered below will be sent to the visitors email address @Model.Info.Email</div>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewMeeting.Title, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewMeeting.Title, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewMeeting.StartTime, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewMeeting.StartTime, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewMeeting.EndTime, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewMeeting.EndTime, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewMeeting.SubjectId, new { @Value = Model.Info.SubjectId })
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send Invite" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The Model is:

```
public class Meeting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Reason for invitation")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public string HostEmail { get; set; }

    public string HostMobile { get; set; }    
}

public class MeetingsDBContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
}

public class ReinviteVisitorModel
{
    public Visitor Info;
    public Meeting NewMeeting;
    public List<Meeting> Meetings;
}
```

The Controller action is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateMeeting(Meeting meeting)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ReinviteVisitor2", "Home", new { visitorId = meeting.SubjectId });
    }
```

I have fields in the model such as Id which I am expecting the database to populate which I was going to write in the the action CreateMeeting(). Do all fields in the Model have to be used in the form?

Comment: You're redirecting to another action `ReinviteVisitor2`, plz add its code. What's the file name of the view by the way?

Comment: The Model you pass and the Model you used are different, pretty much why it returns null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model in your view is typeof `ReinviteVisitorModel` which means the signature of the POST method must match since your posting `ReinviteVisitorModel`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateMeeting(ReinviteVisitorModel model)
```

alternatively you can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` to strip the `NewMeeting` prefix from the names of the form controls your are posting.

```
public ActionResult CreateMeeting([Bind(Prefix="NewMeeting")]Meeting model)
```

Side note: Remove `new { @Value = Model.Info.SubjectId }` from the hidden input and instead set the value of `NewMeeting.SubjectId` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: OK got the first part working. But if I move the hidden field as you have described it is null (Meeting.SubjectId) when passed to CreateMeeting action. I think the form creates a new Meeting object?

Comment: I did not say to move the hidden input. Just use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NewMeeting.SubjectId)`, but set its value in the GET method so you get true 2-way model binding e.g. `NewMeeting.SubjectId = Info.SubjectId;` (its bad practice to override the functionality of the `HtmlHelper` methods by setting the `value` attribute)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `ReinviteVisitorModel` model in your `Action`

Update you action with this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateMeeting(ReinviteVisitorModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ReinviteVisitor2", "Home", new { visitorId = model.NewMeeting.SubjectId });
}
```